# Where are compiled JSP Java (*__jsp.java) files?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, struts, jstl

I am getting a `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException` in one of the jsp files that my website is trying to render (`survey.jsp`). However, the stack trace does not give me the the specific line in jsp where it fails but rather the line number where it fails in (`survey_jsp.java:787`), which seems to be the compiled JSP file. Where do I find such files, so that I know what line is throwing this exception?

Thanks

**EDIT:** These files live in the `/work` directory if you are using tomcat as Will suggested in the comment below.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The compiled JSP files are by default available in the `/work` folder of the Tomcat environment. There should be a subfolder `Catalina` which in turn has a subfolder representing the domain name which defaults to `localhost`. There in turn should be the project folder which in turn contains package hierarchy `org.apache.jsp` with therein the compiled JSP files.

```
Tomcat
 |-- backup
 |-- bin
 |-- conf
 |-- lib
 |-- logs
 |-- temp
 |-- webapps
 `-- work
      `-- Catalina
           `-- localhost
                `-- projectname
                     `-- org
                          `-- apache
                               `-- jsp
                                    |-- survey_jsp.class
                                    `-- survey_jsp.java    <--- here
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there should be a *root cause* part in the stacktrace of the `JspException` which usually contains more detail about the real root cause of the problem. Read a bit further in the stacktrace. By the way, do you know that putting raw Java code in JSP files is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)? It makes problems harder to debug as you encounter now.

Comment: I am using struts to enforce the MVC structure, so no raw java is being used inside the jsp. The error arises because it " Cannot find bean: "blah" in any scope"

Comment: Then figuring the generated Java source code offers no additional benefit. It would only be all abracadabra for you. The real work should be done on understanding the *real* error message (which you finally figured down in the stacktrace) and then fixing the view/model/configuration accordingly. I.e. make sure that the bean "blah" is in the scope.

Comment: I've never ever seen JSP files without raw Java code, tbh.

Comment: In my case my tomcats work folder is an empty folder. How to update this folder

Comment: @BalusC I am seeing WEB-002dINF folder in the path mentioned in the answer. e.g. "opt/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/app/error/error_jsp.class"  Any idea what is the logic of WEB-002dINF naming convention? I want to mark some paths as whitelisted for Path Traversal.

Answer (score 10):

I am using `Intellij` to learn JavaEE and in order to view some features when jsp translating into servlet, I also have to find the file.

I didn't find it below `<tomcat_home>/work/*`. I finally find that the file is under the  **`~/.IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/`** folder( tree structure showing from `~/.IntelliJIdea15/system/tomcat/`)!

```
Name related to project name
 |-- conf
 |-- logs
 `-- work
      `-- Catalina
           `-- localhost
                `-- projectname and type
                     `-- org
                          `-- apache
                               `-- jsp
                                    |-- survey_jsp.class
                                    `-- survey_jsp.java    <--- here
```

If you still can't find it under Intellij's home folder, you may have to try using

```
find . | grep 'nameOfYourJsp_jsp.java'
```

in suitable parent folder.

Comment: This is only the case if the IDE is configured to take over deployment control from server. This is not true in normal/production environments.

Comment: I didn't make any configuration for it. So it is the default behavior of intellij?

Answer (score 5):

If the page did not compile you should find it somewhere below `<tomcat>/work/*`. The full path depends on you environment. If you can't find it there you should start your Tomcat in debug mode, it definitly keeps `.java` files failed to compile (Tomcat 7).

Answer (score 2):

adding one more scenario: with eclipse and tomcat to run Spring MVC:
you should find the _jsp.java files in your workspace folder:

\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost[project Name]\org\apache\jsp\

also this is really based on your setting in tomcat:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, compiled jsps were under

```
 /var    
   |--cache    
       |-- tomcat8    
            |--Catalina
                   |--localhost
                          |--projectname
                                 |-- (etc...)
```

Answer (score 0):

from the oracle document

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException :: A generic exception known to the JSP engine; uncaught JspExceptions will result in an invocation of the errorpage machinery.

i even used to get this whenever i used scriplets in my code

my advice : don't use scripltes even it might seems to develop code easy but with all due respects, its a big head - ache to maintain a scriplets code. TRUST ME

Answer (score -4):

C:\Users\ADMIN\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JspDemo\org\apache\jsp

change link according to you project name.