# HTTP Status 500 null pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, netbeans, mysql-workbench

A jsp website I made was working perfectly until I scripted the database, delete the database, changed script to DELETE on cascade and re-run the database. now when I run the website Im getting the following error :S what could it be? (using Netbeans, JSP & Hibernate)

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: What's happening on line 337 of index_jsp.java?

Comment: Dont have line 337 in index because it is including a header & footer..

Comment: Look at the Java version of your index.jsp file, it should have the line that is failing. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files for the location of those files.

Comment: Why's this question tagged with "mysql-workbench"? It has nothing to do with that product.

Comment: Thanks Roy, that was really helpful I managed to get my website up and running again :)