# display an image from a blob field using servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i created a jsp page that calls another jsp page that show an image took from a blob field in my mysql db:

```
<img src="blob.jsp">
```

it works. But, somewhere in this forum i read that this is not the right way to do it. I should, instead, using a servlet this way:

```
 <img src="servlet_name">
```

I created a servlet, but it doesent show me the image it shows me this

```
ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿí$Photoshop 3.08BIMí ResolutionHH8BIM FX Global Lighting Anglex8BIMFX Global Altitude8BIMó Print Flags 8BIM Copyright Flag8BIM'Japanese Print Flags 8BIMõColor Halftone SettingsH/fflff/ff¡™š2Z5-8BIMøColor Transfer Settingspÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿèÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿèÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿèÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿè8BIM Layer State8BIM Layer Groups8BIMGuides@@8BIM URL overrides8BIMSlicesuƒD Untitled-1Dƒ8BIMICC Untagged Flag
```

This is my simple servlet

```
package Jeans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/BlobDisplay")
public class BlobDisplay extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    GestioneDB gestioneDB ;


    public BlobDisplay() {
        super();       
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
            {       
        Blob image = null;
        byte[ ] imgData = null ;
        String query = null;
        query = request.getParameter(query);        

        gestioneDB = new GestioneDB();

        ResultSet rs =  gestioneDB.rs("select immagine_principale from news where id ='217'");

            try{
            if (rs.next()) {
            image = rs.getBlob("immagine_principale");
            imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());

            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
            o.write(imgData);
            o.flush();
            o.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}    
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  

         this.doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `immagine_principale` row contains binary data of an image?

Comment: Yess im sure. In my page i get something like ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿí$Photoshop 3.08BIMí because it is the way the image is saved in a blob field in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is a debugging hint for now.

JSPs are just "inside out" servlets and they are translated to servlets by the container.  Since your JSP works and your servlet doesn't, why don't you check out (and post) the generated servlet.  If you are using tomcat, it would be in a [file called `blob__jsp.java` deep in the work directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files).  Then compare the calls and set up of your servlet and the generated servlet.

(My first guess is the content type, but you seem to be setting that)

Comment: Even after you visit your JSP?  Try either putting tomcat in debug mode or putting a temporary error in your JSP (eg: "int a = 5/0") and then visiting it.

Comment: I was able to make it work following this guide http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/DisplayBlobServlet.htm that uses a different code. Maybe if i want to use a servlet i have to use a code a little different from the one i used in my jsp page