# IE8 rendering takes more than 12 seconds compared to 3 seconds on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have web page which takes 3-4 seconds on IE11 but it takes more than 12 seconds on IE8. 
I have below tags in head.

```
     meta charset="utf-8"  
     meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"  
     meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.1)"  
     meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.1)"
```

I'm trying to figure out what is causing this issue and what can be done to reduce IE8 rendering time.

Note: JSP has 5-6K lines of code.

Linked Question: [JSP load taking more than 12 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084905/jsp-load-taking-more-than-12-seconds/31086112#31086112)

Comment: @BalusC I resolved the issue for IE8 to bring down the load to 3-4 seconds. Added all JS code from script tag into single JS file and imported it on JSP. Subsequently added setTimeout for jquery change events which were suppose to be loaded in background. I am working on using minified version of JS file and including JS at the end and see if it would improve the performance further. Thank you for your time and input on this. If you could provide me with any link to analyze and improve web page performance that would be helpful too.