# jsp <% %> tags is displaying in browser and html tags is working fine when I am running the web application in server

Tags: java, jsp

```
<% response.sendRedirect("sitesList.action"); %>
```

When I am running the application in server then jsp tags are displaying in browser. Please suggest what is the correct way.

Comment: [This](http://jsp.davidcastro.com/setupenvironmenttutorial.jsp) is helpful. You have to run tomcat server. It looks like you just opened your file with browser.

Comment: yes i already run tomcat6 server

Comment: http://tools.auditmysite.com/
html content is getting but struts tags is not working

Comment: Why do you do the redirect in the JSP ? Do it in the controller. Besides scriptlets are "banned" in most modern projects

Comment: when I am running the web application https://tools.auditmysite.com/ then jsp page is not excuting and its downloading. This site is working on http but when I am using https that time jsp page is not executing and html page is working. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.use`<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>` in the file of first line.

2.check the file name is ".jsp"

try it.

Comment: when I am running the web application https://tools.auditmysite.com/ then jsp page is not excuting and its downloading. This site is working on http but when I am using https that time jsp page is not executing and html page is working. please help me.

Comment: Usually JSP is auto be compiled to JAVA by server, may be you can check your JAVA code that compiled from JSP, to check your code be currently compiled, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files)  is information for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you used `&lt;` and `&gt;` for scriptlet tag?
if yes then please remove that and use`<% %>` scriptlet tag.

Comment: we are not using &lt; and &gt tag

Comment: <% response.sendRedirect("sitesList.action"); %>  but i m uplaoding the war file through parallel plesk but struts tags is not working in server