# Getting additional line break in JSON using response.getwriter().write in JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I have a huge JSON that need to be rendered using response.getwriter.write() using a JSP. After getting the parsed JSON
using gson , when I am trying to render the JSON using  response.getwriter.write() , I am getting a line break in generated output and thus making the JSON invalid. I have checked this line break is coming when the JSON size is getting huge. Can you please help , how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Review your JSP and check if there are any link break between tags. For example, there is a link break between `<%@page language="java" %>` and `<%@page import=" java.util.*" %>`

```
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import=" java.util.*" %><%@page import=" java.io.*" %><%
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write("...");
%>
<% //there is another new line char between scriptlet tags.
%>
```

Another way is check the .java/.class file generated by server. For Tomcat, check the answer of [Where are compiled JSP Java (*__jsp.java) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files)