# Is JSP page a java class?

Tags: java, jsp

**JSP** page in its lifecycle translated into **.java** file, but is **JSP** page itself a **java class**?
Confused and need help.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833711/where-are-compiled-jsp-java-jsp-java-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSPs are compiled into Java Servlets, and Java servlets are classes. So yes, the JSP is compiled to a Java class. The name is usually automatically generated, and is visible in any stack traces (if you throw an `Exception`).

Comment: yes in lifecycle it is compiled to .java class, but I'm confused about is a JSP page itself a java class? Can we declare aJSP page as a java class?
btw thanks for the answer

Comment: It **compiles** to a Java class, but it cannot be ***declared*** as a Java class. You can **directly** create a `Servlet` (which is what a JSP compiles to), and you can use `<%! %>` to ***defined*** **methods** in a JSP. Exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages):

> A JavaServer Pages compiler is a program that parses JSPs, and transforms them into executable **Java Servlets**.

And from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29):

> Java Servlet technology provides Web developers with a simple, consistent mechanism for extending the functionality of a Web server and for accessing existing business systems. Servlets are server-side Java EE components that generate responses (typically HTML pages) to requests (typically HTTP requests) from clients. A servlet can almost be thought of as **an applet that runs on the server side**

Since applets are classes, hence, a JSP is a class.

Answer (score 0):

> The intend behind JSP is Actually makes easier for JAVA developer + front end Developer to
>   write not only Java code also need to write HTML code and other which
>   is easily stuff with html code too for full fill the task complete.

so, let's say, my jsp page is `home.jsp`, then it's translating `from .jsp to .java` by `home_jsp.java` which will enclosed all `non-java code` into `java`.

and finally `home_jsp.class` file generate which will run on `JVM`.

> JSP page life cycle and many of the capabilities of JSP pages (in
>   particular the dynamic aspects) are determined by Java Servlet
>   technology.

Now, i hope you are little bit clear on your query that *was*,

**JSP page in its lifecycle translated into .java file, but is JSP page itself a java class?**

*Best of luck...!!!*

Answer (score 0):

A JSP pages compiler is a program that parses JSPs, and transforms them into executable Java Servlets and that java Servlets is a simple java class.